# What is the second automatically generated element within a component's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`props.children` is automatically included when a React component is created. Given something like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'val'
}

const Parent = () => <Child obj={obj} />

const Child = props => <GrandChild/>

const GrandChild = (...props) => <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
```

will print: `[{},{}]`

Changing `Child` to be

```
const Child = props => <GrandChild>child element</GrandChild>
```

will print: `[{"children":"child element"},{}]`

So I guess the first object is reserved for `props.children`

Changing `Child` to be

```
const Child = props => <GrandChild a="sth else">child element</GrandChild>
```

will print `[{"a":"sth else","children":"child element"},{}]`

There is still an empty object there. Removing the `...` on `Grandchild` removes both the encompassing array, and the last element.

What is this extra element? Why is it removed by the removal of the spread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stateless component is called with `props` and [legacy context](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#referencing-context-in-stateless-functional-components).

```
const GrandChild = (props, context) => {   
  return <div>{context.something}</div>
}

GrandChild.contextTypes = {
  something: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Is it only passed to stateless components?

Comment: @1252748 You can access legacy context in stateful components as well with `this.context`, but the [new context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is preferred.